# how to model a connection to a resource, with rudimentary event processing

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented, mvc, observer-pattern

For my simple [MUD client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD_client) I'm using Apache Telnet (no, not ssh).  A mud client is a strange beast:

> Generally, a MUD client is a very basic telnet client that lacks VT100 terminal emulation and the capability to perform telnet negotiations.
>       ...
>       Standard features seen in most MUD clients include ANSI color support, aliases, triggers and scripting.
>       - Wikipedia

I would **like** for a not-yet-written `Controller` to have a reference to `TelnetConnection` and just use it for a higher level of abstraction for I/O, but all attempts to prise this class apart fail for me.  `TelnetConnection` seems to take on responsibility for everything, and then some, and just keep growing.

```
package telnet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;
import player.GameAction;
import player.DataFromRegex;
import player.Regex;

public class TelnetConnection implements Observer {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TelnetConnection.class.getName());
    private TelnetClient telnetClient = new TelnetClient();
    private InputOutput inputOutput = new InputOutput();
    private Regex regexParser = new Regex();
    private DataFromRegex data = null;
    private Logic logic = new Logic();

    public TelnetConnection() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        try {
            int port = 3000;
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("rainmaker.wunderground.com");
            telnetClient.connect(host, port);
            inputOutput.readWriteParse(telnetClient.getInputStream(), telnetClient.getOutputStream());
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        inputOutput.addObserver(this);
    }

    private void sendAction(GameAction action) throws IOException {
        log.info(action.toString());
        byte[] actionBytes = action.getAction().getBytes();
        OutputStream outputStream = telnetClient.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(actionBytes);
        outputStream.write(13);
        outputStream.write(10);
        outputStream.flush();
    }

    private void sendActions(Deque<GameAction> gameActions) {
        while (!gameActions.isEmpty()) {
            GameAction action = gameActions.remove();
            try {
                sendAction(action);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        String line = null;
        if (o instanceof InputOutput) {
            line = inputOutput.getLine();
            log.fine(line);
            data = regexParser.parse(line);
            Deque<GameAction> gameActions = logic.getActions(data);
            sendActions(gameActions);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TelnetConnection();
    }

}
```

Part of the difficulty lies within the `InputOutput` class, which is adapted from `IOUtil` from Apache.  (For some reason, I cannot include the link to to the Apache source code.)

Once I send the `InputStream` to `InputOutput` there needs to be callback using `Observable` to then send the String data for matching and searching?  And then get back **what** after matching and searching the text?

The trick being, in terms of I/O:

1. capture console input
2. print remote output from the MUD server to the console like regular telnet
3. some regex/etc on the remote output, *concurrent* with open, unterminated streams.

This last requirement seems to make an odd beast for which I cannot envision the flow of control and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to simplify the nitty gritty implementation details into a class called `TelnetConnection`, I definitely think that would be a wise idea, however it may be that you cannot do it with simply one class.  You may need to have a secondary class which deals with the asynchronous aspect of this.  Lets call this class `TelnetObserver` which implements `Observer`.

Now in this way, it is still asynchronous, which makes your life difficult, so lets make it synchronous.  Make `TelnetObserver` implement `Future<String>`.  The idea is that you call "get()" whenever you're ready for the next line of input (waiting until input is available if necessary).

Of course this doesn't happen on its own, we must make it synchronous by using an instance of `CountDownLatch`.  The purpose of `CountDownLatch` is to make a thread wait for an asynchronous job to finish within a certain timeframe.  [I found an excellent example of this implementation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180419/wrapping-an-asynchronous-computation-into-a-synchronous-blocking-computation).

Once you have this, `TelnetConnection` will handle the connection logic.  From there, `TelnetConnection` could also handle the parsing of the individual lines, but I wouldn't recommend it.  I would create another class `TelnetParser` which does that for you, given the input from `TelnetObserver`.  The resulting `Object` would then be returned to any listeners for input.  Alternatively on output, you use the same `TelnetParser` to convert from an `Object` to a String which `TelnetObserver` could send.

The basic interface for `TelnetParser` would likely look something like this:

```
public class TelnetParser {
    public Object parseFromString(String) {
        ...
    }
    public String parseToString(Object) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The end result is that you have a model object which you can call upon to receive input or to send output.  This returns control back to the caller, or in this case your class `Controller`!  I hope that helps.  Good luck in your endeavor!

Comment: I'm not sure about `Future` in this case, because the client has 2 main functions:  1.) regular telnet, let the user type commands  2.)  some automated responses.   It's *not supposed* to do anything after x seconds, in fact that probably breaks any number of game rules, and is somewhat nonsensical.  If nothing is happening, then nothing is happening.  It sounds like you're doing the opposite of putting a thread to sleep to pause output...?  I'll have to read up on this :)        **very** interesting answer

Comment: Strictly speaking, you could even drop the Future.  As for the `CountDownLatch`, it uses a `Timer` to determine when timeout has occurred, but otherwise, the current thread sleeps while waiting for input, so it should be fairly efficient.